# Arrange barcharts side by side with ggplot2 and R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am struggling to  display two barcharts side by side with the same scale

My code looks like this

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
#dataframe definition
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
mydata <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=c('yes','no'),c=seq(2,20,2))

plot1<- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=factor(mydata$b), y=100*a), order=f, fill=grey) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geo    m="bar", colour="black")+xlab("Factor b") + 
  ylab("Value of a")    

plot2<- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=factor(mydata$b), y=c), order=f) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar", colour="black")+xlab("Factor b") + 
  ylab("Value of b")    

grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, ncol=2)
```

That produces the following image.

[image: Image output from ggplot2]

I want to position them in a way the vertical axis has the same scale for both of the barcharts. 
I couldn't find any documentation on the gridExtra manual.

Comment: use facets instead of gridExtra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

mydata <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=c('yes','no'),c=seq(2,20,2))
df <- melt(mydata, id.vars="b")
df[which(df$variable=="a"),]$value <- df[which(df$variable=="a"),]$value * 100
ggplot(df, aes(factor(b), value))  + 
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar", colour="black") + facet_grid(.~variable)


# If you need free scales, then:

ggplot(df, aes(factor(b), value))  + 
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar", colour="black") + 
  facet_wrap( ~variable, scales = "free_y")
```

Comment: Minor point: the OP multiplied the y values in group a by 100 first, so there's one more line in there before creating the plot.

Comment: I am trying it on another dataframe and it says:Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class function
Here is the head
    > head(mydata)
         neg1   prod     negdiff
       1 0.002052033 Search 0.001988404
       2 0.001882204 Search 0.001602449
       3 0.002441669 Search 0.002168546
       4 0.002793366 Search 0.001892196
       5 0.001386803 Search 0.001182116